# C# Events firing on wrong thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-2.0, serial-port

All

I have an application that allows a user to communicate with multiple serial devices.
A manager class is used to start the application, which creates a new thread for each serial device. Inside this thread, the serial device is created and the thread and serial device object are stored inside the manager class for later when needed.

The serial device class then creates a com port class on it's own new thread which is used to connect to the com port and send / receive data. When data is received an event is fired up to the serial device class which in turn fires an event to the manager class, which in turn fires an event to the UI to alert the user that new data has arrived.

My problem comes that when the com port class fires it's event to notify the serial port class, the serial port class receives the event and continues processing under the com port thread. Likewise if the user sends any information down to the com port, it all runs under the UI thread.

I will add code as an edit later, but for now, if anyone can spot anything obvious I would be seriously greatful.

I have tried receiving the event in the serial device class and then invoking a method to see if that makes it run under the correct thread but that was no good.

I know the serial device thread is running as I do an Application.Run inside the class after it's created it's com port classes.

I'm not using any background workers as these threads are meant to exist for the life of the application and I understand background workers are meant to be used for short running calculations.

Many thanks

EDIT:

Forgot to mention, this is a Winforms app in .NET 2.0, so no Dispatcher available

EDIT:
Okay, so it looks like that the information is being passed up inside the DataReceived thread (I think as it isn't the com port thread either).
I also tried using a BackgroundWorker for the serial device class but this also didn't make any difference.
Help?

Comment: Are you using the [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class internally?

Comment: It is very unclear.  Are you using the SerialPort.DataReceived event?  Then yes, you receive the data on a threadpool thread.  You'll eventually have to use Control.BeginInvoke() to get the UI updated.

Comment: Yes it is a winform app. Receiving the events is not the problem. I receive all the notifications, just on the wrong thread. What I want to do is for the  serial device class to process the notification on it's own thread, not the com port or UI thread. And yes, it is using the DataReceived event.

Comment: My issue is that if the UI sends an update down the line to the manager, then to the serial device class and then to the com port class, I don't want them all to happen on the UI thread, and vice versa. Otherwise things get held up

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you need to create a kind of messaging mechanism to send messages from the UI thread to the correct port-thread. A queue might work. Let the UI thread post messages on the queue and have the port-thread process these messages.

Switching from the port-thread to the UI thread can be done using `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`

Is this what you are looking for?

**EDIT** I am assuming a WinForms application

Comment: ... was also going to suggest using the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher class.

Comment: Believe the OP stated that this was a .NET 2.0 app, and I don't think the Dispatcher is available in that version. As for the suggestion of a message queue implementation, I agree with that notion wholeheartedly. Was involved in the design of a similar application about 18 months ago with similar issues, and a message queue solved the problem very nicely. The queue can live independently of the UI thread, and the UI can talk to the queue as it needs and should alleviate (or at least greatly simplify) the thread switching issues. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

.NET 2.0 has SynchronizationContext.  It's a slight pain (you have to pass the context from the UI thread to the others) but it should do the trick.

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for getting back to me. This looks good, what I've tried to do is create a SynchronizationContext object in the constructor of the serial device class, but this seems to always be null? I used `SynchronizationContext obj = SynchronizationContext.Current;`. I then tried to create it inside the manager class, during the initialisation of the serialdevice class, but again it was null.

Comment: If I do create a new SynchronizationContext, then it still doesn't show the correct thread name...

Comment: Only the UI thread will have a SynchronizationContext; you will have to pass it to the threads you create one way or another.  There's some more info and an example here: http://daveonsoftware.blogspot.com/2007/11/dispatcher-versus-synchronizationcontex.html

Comment: In that case, how could I marshall one non-UI thread onto another? Invoking seems like it should be the way forward, but it isn't making any difference.

Comment: Oh...onto another *non-UI* thread.  Hm.  I wonder if you could have those threads create their own SynchronizationContexts; this means you will have to work out a message queue kind of thing, e.g. the thread has a `List<Action>` and all operations go into and are run from that in a loop.  I don't know if there's an easy answer but ultimately I think you're going to have to turn your thread into a glorified message pump of its own.